# How to execute Select query inside loop in batch script?

Tags: sql, batch-file, cmd, scripting, sqlplus

I am trying to execute a select query at interval of few seconds to get latest values. But it connect to database every time it execute select statement inside my batch script. I want to connect only once and then execute select queries. I tried following code.

```
@echo off
:loop
cls
(
echo user/pass@xyz
echo select COL1 from TABLE;
)| sqlplus 

SLEEP 5
goto loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this sentence:

```
@echo select COL1 from TABLE; | sqlplus user/pass@xyz
```

Comment: I want to execute same query at 5 seconds, but i want to connect only once as it takes time. I want process to be like Connect, execute, execute ....execute